# Array value is set to zero after the whole process generated by user

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, integer, 2d

I want to create a minigame which select random buttons from an array of game objects and store the value in an array. After the first step is completed the user need to tap on the same buttons or he will lose. The problem is when I want to compare the values from this two arrays, every value from index 0-2 is set to 0 in both arrays. I tried to debug the adding part and that works fine, even in my editor I can see the stored values. Here is a photo:
[storedobjectsEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZMeI.png). I even put two for loops to check the values from array in the game, instead of getting 3 prints I get 6 of them, first 3 represent the values right and the other 3 have value = 0 (this apply to both arrays). In my CheckWin() the result will be always true because the values which are compared there are 0 for every position from both arrays. I can't figure it out what force the arrays to have all components set to zero in that method. Here is the script:

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] buttons;
    [SerializeField] private int[] culoriINT;
    [SerializeField] private int[] culoriComparareINT;
    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    private bool win = false;


    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ChangeColors2());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("INT vector[" + i + "]: " + culoriINT[i]);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < culoriComparareINT.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Al doilea vector[" + i + "]: " + culoriComparareINT[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    IEnumerator ChangeColors2()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons.Length; j++)
        {
            var randomBtn = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, buttons.Length);
            buttons[randomBtn].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;

            var introducereIndex = buttons[randomBtn].GetComponent<IndexButtons>().index;
            culoriINT[index] = introducereIndex;

            Debug.Log($"Index adaugat {introducereIndex} total {culoriINT.Length}");
            index++;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); //seteaza coloare alb pe acelas buton in cazu in care nimereste acelas sa se vada
            buttons[randomBtn].GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
            Debug.Log("verde");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }


    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        index2++;
    }
    public void numePeClick()
    {
        if (index2 < buttons.Length)
        {
            string a = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
            culoriComparareINT[index2] = Convert.ToInt32(a);
            Debug.Log($"Index adaugat {Convert.ToInt32(a)} total {culoriComparareINT.Length}");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Array plin");
        }
    }

    public void CheckWin()
    {
        win = true;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < culoriINT.Length; i++)
        {
            if (culoriINT[i] != culoriComparareINT[i])
            {
                win = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                win = true;
            }

        }

        if (win)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ai castigat!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Ai pierdut!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Comment: ...also consider caching all those `Image`s rather than perform `GetComponent<Image>` in order to improve performance

Comment: @MickyD I always thought co-routines are the way to go, as they were posted as answers in many places. Why using them is a bad habit? Can I use them (assuming I do it correctly) in unity and opt to use something else (async/await maybe) in other c# projects? Or is it maybe a topic for a separate question?

Comment: _"as they were posted as answers in many places"_ - so was `Application.DoEvents` and the equivalent in VB.  Sadly all 3 lead to _application re-entrancy_.  _"as they were posted as answers in many places"_ - well maybe, but then again the same can be said for `Application.DoEvents`.   If you know `async/await` better to use that.   Even better, **99%** of questions/code on SO re Unity re coroutines can be easily replaced with a time-based lerp function - the simplest of all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two instances of the same Script component in your scene. One of them has the correct values `3,2,3`, the other one has the wrong values `0,0,0`. This is why six values get printed to the console instead of three with a single input.